# 301 Redirect Within Django for www Subdomain

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-urls

I'm using DNSimple and Heroku for my Python/Django app, but both with and without the "www" is going to the site, and basically giving me two different duplicate sites. I'm supposed to do a redirect form within my app to solve this problem. How do I create a 301 redirect from no "www" to the "www" within Django?

Answer (score 1):

Just return a redirect case the request is made for the naked domain.

```
if not request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '').startswith('www'):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
               'http://www.example.com/' + request.get_full_path()
           )
```

You can make it a decorator or put it on the base class if you are using class based views, but performance is better if you handle this redirection at the webserver level.

You are using PaaS providers, this is a common use case and they both have it covered, ask their help desk.

The recipe to do this with mod_rewrite is a bit off-topic because it is not related to programming; something like this should be placed in the virtual host config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```